# Issue while hosting through github pages

Tags: javascript, html, git, css, github

I uploaded a static website to Github, and hosted it through Github pages.
And it was successfully uploaded to internet. But the problem is the images were not loaded.
And then I identified that, I didnt upload the image files associated with that website to Github.
And now, even if I add those image files to Github, still it is not showing the images online.

Github Repo link : https://github.com/subinedge/CyberPunk 
Live site link : https://subinedge.github.io/CyberPunk/ 
You can see the issue at "Meet the authors section" in the website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those images do not exist in the [`gh-pages` branch](https://github.com/subinedge/CyberPunk/tree/gh-pages/img) your site is probably being deployed from.

You can change the branch your site is being deployed from in [your repository's settings view](https://github.com/subinedge/CyberPunk/settings) – scroll down to find the GitHub Pages section – or you can update the `gh-pages` branch to match master.

Comment: I have updated now, the default branch as github pages, but still its not working.

Comment: ohh sorry man !! In master page only, those images are there... kk fine , i will add it